# Upgraded to GNOME 3.10, Eclipse stopped working! What do?

Tags: gnome, eclipse

My machine is running Ubuntu 13.10 GNOME.
Yesterday I upgraded to GNOME 3.10 (from the included GNOME 3.8).

Now, my copy of Eclipse Kepler refuses to open!  I see the splash screen, and then it disappears.  For a while it was opening a blank Eclipse window (no toolbars, panels, or anything), but now it won't even do that.

Any suggestions for recovery?

Answer (score 0):

The errors inevitably reveals if you have not right distributive. If your Eclipse installed at 13.04, for using at 13.10 you need distributive for 13.10 and reinstall at least.

Answer (score 0):

It may be related to [eclipse bug 421127](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=421127).

Its target milestone is 4.4 M6 (Luna).